# How do I force Pycharm to recognize and use Python 3.6.1 libraries?

Tags: linux-mint, development, python3

Same as above. Recently I broke my system and then wiped and reinstalled. I initially managed to get python 3.6 working in Pycharm with a new installed before breaking things again. I didn't do anything special and merely retraced my steps only to find Pycharm only seeing 2.7 and 3.5 instead of 3.6 on my 3rd install.

I want to make use of the most current version of Python due to the features it's released. How do I set up environment variables to recognize 3.6.1 for development purposes? I did it a few times on Windows but merely went into Advanced system settings and added a few lines in a window.

I installed Python 3.6.1 successfully on Mint; How can I duplicate the above process for Pycharm on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Project` -> `Project interpreter` -> click on the little wheel and select `Add local` and then select your 3.6.1 environment

Comment: Despite installing it using these instructions: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-linuxmint/ It didn't work. I then tried adding a ppa from this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get and got these errors:

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.1-1~16.04.york0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6:
 python3.6 depends on python3.6-minimal (= 3.6.1-1~16.04.york0); however:
  Package python3.6-minimal is not configured yet.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6-minimal
 python3.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I am unable to change the interpreter from 2.7 or 3.5 as default choices. There is nothing to select in the drop down menu that mentions anything other than 2.7 or 3.5

Comment: What errors did you get when you try to install python with the first link you posted?

Comment: A lot hinging on a variation of a certain term... I don't recall though I suppose I should keep copies of all of my outputs now shouldn't I.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we can force a project to use a specific before configuring it first. PyCharm auto detects available interpreters and we will have to configure the project to use a specific interpreter and give it a name.

*The following is from the Help docs from PyCharm:*

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

PyCharm helps assign a Python interpreter for a project.

So doing, each one of the projects, opened in the same window, can have an interpreter of its own, selected from the list of available interpreters.

**Note** that PyCharm stores only the interpreter name in the project settings.

To configure Python SDK for the current project, follow these steps:

> 1. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog box, and click Project Interpreter page.
> 2. In the Projects pane, choose the desired project.
> 3. Choose SDK from the list of available Python interpreters and virtual environments.
>      This list includes:
>
>    - Python interpreters, which reside in standard locations.
>    - Virtual environments, which reside under the project folder, or under the folder specified as an environment variable WORKON_HOME.
>    - Other Python interpreters, installed locally or remotely.
> 4. If the desired interpreter is not in the list, click the cogwheel icon, and configure the desired interpreter as described in the section Configuring Available Python Interpreters.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated to zorin os 15 (ubuntu based) and installed python3.7.4 alongside the python3.6 & python2.7 but my pycharm community edition wasn't showing that latest version in the interpreter drop down menu so i did couple of things and it worked for me.

- find out the path of your interpreter with `which python3.x` in terminal ( x = the decimal version number, example: `which python3.6`)
  in my case the latest one was in `/usr/local/bin/` rather than `/usr/bin/`

  - You will need to add the interpreter to the list of available interpreters.

Go to `Settings > Project Interpreter > Add > System Interpreter` in pycharm and add that interpreter going to the location you found out in the terminal.